# Discord Python Music bot Error

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I recently started to learn python by making bots for Discord. Now I'm making a Music bot but I got an error and couldn't find where the error is. Can you guys help, please? It joins the channel but gives the Error3 in Chat and if I write !Play (URL) again, it gives the Error 4 in chat.

Here is the Code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client ()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(client.user.name)
    print("-------------------")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("!stop"):
        try:
            voice_client = client_voice_in(message.server)
            await voice_client.disconnect()
        except AttributeError:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "I'm not connected.")
        except Exception as Hugo:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "Error1_______|type|_______".format(type=Hugo))

    if message.content.startswith("!play"):
        try:
            yt_url = message.content[6:]
            if client.is_voice_connected(message.server):
                try:
                    voice = client.voice_client_in(message.server)
                    players[message.server.id].stop()
                    player = await voice.create_ytdl_player(yt_url, before_options=" -reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1"
                                                                                   " -reconnect_delay_max 5")
                    players[message.server.id] = player
                    player.start()
                except Exception as e:
                    await client.send_message(message.server, "Error2______[Error]".format(error=e))

            if not client.is_voice_connected(message.server):
                try:
                    channel = message.author.voice.voice_channel
                    voice = await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
                    player = await voice.create_ytdl_player(yt_url, before_options=" -reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1"
                                                                                   " -reconnect_delay_max 5")
                    players[message.server.id] = player
                    player.start()
                except Exception as e:
                    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Error3____[error]".format(error=e))
        except Exception as e:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "Error4________[error]".format(error=e))




client.run("I erased the token number before sharing, it's not the problem")
```

Comment: It seems like you have it give you the error type when it errors. What types of errors are you getting?

Comment: @Qwerty in discord chat it gives the error i named „Error3“ when i write !play and gives error when i write !stop as well but nothing in the python window

Comment: by any chance are you following a tutorial? It appears that you except the Exception as e, and format e into the message. So what does e come out out be?

Comment: @Qwerty i followed a german tutorial on youtube, https://youtu.be/rvbwoQF7Njw he made it work but i couldnt figure out my mistake

Comment: a few things, did you download ffmpeg? Also you can see his code here https://gist.github.com/Grewoss/b6f0a99e135f73ff695bb096f140453e and compare it with your own.

Comment: Make sure PyNaCl is installed, run `pip install PyNaCl` also make sure you have done `pip install youtube_dl`

Comment: @Qwerty i downloaded ffmpeg and do i import pynacl in the code after installing ?

Comment: you do not need to import pynacl, import command prompt and type ffmpeg, what happens?

Comment: @Qwerty i have PyNaCl already,ı'm comparing the Code with original now and type ffmpeg where ? importing it into my Code ?

Comment: Hold the windows key and press are, a run box should appear, type cmd and press enter, the the command prompt should come up. In there type ffmpeg and press enter. What happens?

Comment: @Qwerty as I see ı missed the bracked [] when writing the error in excepts,ı changed it and the error is: "name 'players' is not defined"

Comment: @Tayfan you are missing this at the beginning of your code `players = {}`

Comment: @Qwerty when ı write ffmpeg there,it says it's written wrong or not found,and ı didnt do an installisation for that, ı just copied the .exe file into the Folder where the .py file is as the tuto. said

Comment: Alright that's good. See my previous comment and fix it, then try running the code again.

Comment: @Qwerty -_-,dude thank you, ı really did miss that,I can't believe that I tried this to figure out for more than 3.30hrs... It works now but I think it's normal for beginner Level :d and I saw some mistakes of mine by myself while trying to find that as well...

Comment: is it working now? If so I will post that as the answer

Comment: @Qwerty Works perfectly,ı had a Problem for !stop but fixed that as well, Thank you !

Comment: @Qwerty , if you have Knowledge about this as well, how can I do custom search on YouTube for Music without providing a link ?

Comment: you should check out the youtube search api, just look it up, it is more advanced programming, and I don't know your level, so it's hard to reccomend.

Comment: I have now posted the answer

Comment: @Qwerty ok i will look it up, thanks again !

Comment: if the answer given is correct, it should be accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not yet defined the variable players. At the beginning of your code, add this:

`players = {}`

Hope this worked!